# AzureDevOps Pipleline Metrics/Logs in Grafana

Tags: azure-devops, grafana

is it possible to publish Azure DevOps pipeline metrics/logs into Grafana. I'm looking to build Grafana dashboard to display success/failire of Azure Build & Release pipeline.

I don't want metrics from the applications deployed via the pipeline (which can be done by plugging-in grafana to Azure Monitor)

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://github.com/webdevops/azure-devops-exporter

This is an Prometheus exporter for Azure DevOps. It scrapes projects, builds, build times (elapsed and queue wait time), agent pool utilization and active pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [grafana service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/grafana?view=azure-devops) out of the box for release pipelines.  It doesn't appear to be anything similar for the build pipelines.

Comment: Grafana service hook is for Annotations but not for logs.
There is an option to download the logs using the ‘system.debug = true’ variable, as .txt files.

But then 
1- can raw data (.txt files) can be used as data sources in Grafana
2- can I use something like logstash for data aggregation, to be consumed by Grafana
3- even if 1 & 2 above are possible, I wanted an automated solution

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to publish Azure DevOps pipeline metrics/logs into
> Grafana

As far as I know, this is currently impossible to achieve. Azure devops only provides service hook and [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Payoneer.grafana-annotations) for annotations but not for logs. Currently only the [integration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-monitor-logs-in-grafana-now-in-public-preview/) of Grafana and Microsoft Azure Monitor logs is provided.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. In addition, you can also new topic on [Grafana Community](https://community.grafana.com/) for more help.

Answer (score -2):

I have been able to extract ADO data via the APIs through a python script & post that in postgres DB & finally displaying it in Grafana

Comment: Hey, without details this answer won't help anyone, apart from maybe showing that it is possible. But thank you for getting back to us at all after the fellow didn't reach out to you.